# Batch that joins url and a line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is there any that joins url and a line
Just like This

base url
http://google.com

input

```
dog
cow
milk
```

output

```
http://google.com/dog
http://google.com/cow
http://google.com/milk
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for %%a in ( dog cat pig ) DO (
    echo http://www.google.com/%%a
)
```